# recyclerview taking too long to display 300 contacts in android

Tags: android

I am fetching contacts from android device. There are 300 contacts in my ddevice. I have written contact fetching process in doInBackground() method of AsynckTask class.So Its taking too long time to display contact in recyclerview in android after cancelling progress dialog opPostExecute() method.Please give me some solution.

DatabaseAdapter class:

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
```

EmsevaHelper helper;

```
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    helper = new Helper(context);
}

public long insertRecord(String name, String number, String photo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Helper.CONTACT_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(Helper.CONTACT_NUMBER, number);
    contentValues.put(Helper.CONTACT_PHOTO, photo);
    long id = 0;
    try {
        id = db.insertOrThrow(Helper.TABLE_NAME_CONTACT, null, contentValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("InsertExce", String.valueOf(e));
    }

    return id;
}

public int getContactCount() {
    int count=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Helper.TABLE_NAME_CONTACT;
    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        count=cursor.getCount();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
       if(cursor!=null)
       {
           cursor.close();
       }
        if(db!=null && db.isOpen())
        {
            db.close();
        }
    }



    return count;
}

public ArrayList<ContactData> getAllRecord() {
    ArrayList<ContactData> contactData = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Helper.TABLE_NAME_CONTACT;
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contactData.add(new ContactData(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), false, cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return contactData;
}

static class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_CONTACT = "CONTACT";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

    private static final String CID = "_id";
    private static final String CONTACT_NAME = "cname";
    private static final String CONTACT_NUMBER = "cnumber";
    private static final String CONTACT_PHOTO = "cphoto";

    private static final String CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_CONTACT + "(" + CID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + CONTACT_NAME + " VARCHAR(100)," + CONTACT_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE ," + CONTACT_PHOTO + " VARCHAR(255));";

    private static final String DROP_CONTACT_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_CONTACT;


    public Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //creating required table.
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE);
            Log.e("TableCreate", "Susseccfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            Log.e("onCreate Exce****", e + "");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //on upgrade drop older tables.
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_CONTACT_TABLE);

            //create new tables.
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("onUpgrade Exce****", e + "");
        }


    }
}
```

}

AsynckTask on fragment:

```
  class ContactLoader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),"Fetching Contact!","Please wait...",true,false);
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        contactData=databaseAdapter.getAllRecord();
        contactAdapter.setContactAdapterData(contactData);
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        rvContactList.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pd.cancel();




    }
}
```

Comment: We would need to see some code.

Comment: 300 contacts is no big deal at all, you are getting the data in a slow way, you need to improve it

Comment: will you need to see adapter class for recycler view?

Comment: try this adapter when your data is `Cursor` based : https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Answer (score 0):

Don't fetch all the item at once, instead use a `scroll listener`. Based on scroll state load more contacts. Initially you can load `50` contacts and then load the further on scrolling down the list. Keep on adding further contacts to the list of contacts and notify the `adapter`.
You can do something like below where you can track various state of scroll:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {

            }

            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                }

            } else if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {

                }
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```